# "Shapes of all inputs must match" error loss function when trying to do custom training with tf.GradientTape()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradienttape, custom-training

I'm using Python 3.7.7. and Tensorflow 2.1.0 with Functional API and Eager Execution.

I'm trying to do [custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function), with an encoder extracted from a U-Net pretrained network:

1. I get the U-Net model without compile it.
2. I have loaded the weights into the model.
3. I have extracted the encoder and decoder from that model.

Then I want to use the encoder with this summary:

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      1664      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      83040     
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 50, 50, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       1048832   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384,832
Trainable params: 5,384,832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I use this function to do the custom training:

```
def train_encoder_unet_custom(model, dataset):
  
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

  for episode in range(num_episodes):
    selected = np.random.permutation(no_of_samples)[:num_shot + num_query]
    # Create our Support Set.
    support_set = np.array(dataset[selected[:num_shot]])
    
    X_train = support_set[:,0,:]
    y_train = support_set[:,1,:]

    loss_value, grads = grad(model, X_train, y_train)

    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

The `grad` function is:

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

def loss(model, x, y, training):
  # training=training is needed only if there are layers with different
  # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  y_ = model(x, training=training)

  return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)

def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=False)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
```

But when I try to run it I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [5,12,12,512] != values[1].shape = [5,25,25,256] [Op:Pack] name: packed
```

In `loss` function, I have checked the values for `y_` variable. `y_` is a list of 6 elements with these shapes:

```
(5, 12, 12, 512)
(5, 25, 25, 256)
(5, 50, 50, 128)
(5, 100, 100, 96)
(5, 200, 200, 64)
(5, 200, 200, 1)
```

Any idea about what is it happening?

If you need more details, please ask me.

This is the full call stack:

```
<ipython-input-133-22827956a9f6> in train_encoder_unet_custom(model, dataset, feat_type, show)
     22     y_valid = query_set[:,1,:]
     23 
---> 24     loss_value, grads = grad(model, X_train, y_train)
     25 
     26     optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

<ipython-input-143-58ff4de686d6> in grad(model, inputs, targets)
     10 def grad(model, inputs, targets):
     11   with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
---> 12     loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, training=False)
     13   return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)

<ipython-input-143-58ff4de686d6> in loss(model, x, y, training)
      6   y_ = model(x, training=training)
      7 
----> 8   return loss_object(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)
      9 
     10 def grad(model, inputs, targets):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py in __call__(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    147     with K.name_scope(self._name_scope), graph_ctx:
    148       ag_call = autograph.tf_convert(self.call, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx())
--> 149       losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    150       return losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(
    151           losses, sample_weight, reduction=self._get_reduction())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    253       try:
    254         with conversion_ctx:
--> 255           return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in converted_call(f, args, kwargs, caller_fn_scope, options)
    455   if conversion.is_in_whitelist_cache(f, options):
    456     logging.log(2, 'Whitelisted %s: from cache', f)
--> 457     return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)
    458 
    459   if ag_ctx.control_status_ctx().status == ag_ctx.Status.DISABLED:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, update_cache)
    337 
    338   if kwargs is not None:
--> 339     return f(*args, **kwargs)
    340   return f(*args)
    341 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py in call(self, y_true, y_pred)
    251           y_pred, y_true)
    252     ag_fn = autograph.tf_convert(self.fn, ag_ctx.control_status_ctx())
--> 253     return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    254 
    255   def get_config(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py in sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits, axis)
   1562     Sparse categorical crossentropy loss value.
   1563   """
-> 1564   y_pred = ops.convert_to_tensor_v2(y_pred)
   1565   y_true = math_ops.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
   1566   return K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, dtype_hint, name)
   1380       name=name,
   1381       preferred_dtype=dtype_hint,
-> 1382       as_ref=False)
   1383 
   1384 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1497 
   1498     if ret is None:
-> 1499       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1500 
   1501     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _autopacking_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
   1500   elif dtype != inferred_dtype:
   1501     v = nest.map_structure(_cast_nested_seqs_to_dtype(dtype), v)
-> 1502   return _autopacking_helper(v, dtype, name or "packed")
   1503 
   1504 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in _autopacking_helper(list_or_tuple, dtype, name)
   1406     # checking.
   1407     if all(isinstance(elem, core.Tensor) for elem in list_or_tuple):
-> 1408       return gen_array_ops.pack(list_or_tuple, name=name)
   1409   must_pack = False
   1410   converted_elems = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in pack(values, axis, name)
   6457       return _result
   6458     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 6459       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6460     except _core._FallbackException:
   6461       pass

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6841   message = e.message + (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
   6842   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6843   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6844   # pylint: enable=protected-access
   6845 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
```

Comment: Can you provide all the elements so I can copy/paste your code and reproduce your error?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks, but I think I'm going to delete my question because the problem is that I don't know how to train an encoder which only output features (numpy array with shape (1, 12, 12, 512)), and I only have an image (numpy array with shape (1, 200, 200, 1)) to compare and compute loss. Thanks.